# openpyxl - format column for date only

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Using `openpyxl` version `2.6.1`

There's a number of unsolved threads on here about trying to format columns. I understand you cannot format an entire column at the moment...only individual cells? Still, I seem unable to do even that. I'm trying to format a column as `'mm/dd/yyyy'`. I also know `NumberFormat()` has been removed. What I have tried last, and "works" (meaning it's the first time I got code to run and post out into the excel spreadsheet) was the code below...but it does not format the column, the result I get in cell `B2` is `TRUE`. What am I missing here?

```
from openpyxl.styles import is_date_format, numbers

s = numbers.is_date_format('mm/dd/yy')
daily_runs_ws['B2'] = s
```

The current cell format (without trying to edit it) is `11/14/2019  12:00:00 AM` for example.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me. `Openpyxl` allows datetime. So, I suggest something like this:

```
import datetime
import openpyxl

dttm = datetime.datetime.strptime("09/12/2018", "%m/%d/%Y")
print(dttm)
cell = ws['A1']
cell.value = dttm
cell.number_format = 'YYYY MMM DD'
```

The way to format a cell is using `.number_format = "format"`.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, at the moment you can't format an entire column as a date using only openpyxl, but you can format any cells (including all written cells in a column) on a document the following way:

```
import openpyxl

document = openpyxl.load_workbook("document.xlsx")  # Opens excel document
sheet = document.active  # Sets active sheet

# To format all written cells in a column (Ex. column "B")
for cell in sheet["B"]:
    cell.number_format = "DD/MM/YYYY"
```

Note that it is very relevant that **this only formats the *written* cells in a column**, all other blank cells after the last written cell (does not apply for blank cells in between written cells) remains with a "General" format unless previously formatted.

Answer (score 0):

`numbers.is_date_format` is a function that openpyxl uses to determine whether a number format is for dates and times. The way you use it will return `True` and set the value of `B2` to True. Which is probably not what you want.

I suggest you read the section of the openpyxl documentation that covers styles. That should answer your questions.